# Rails: Why is my model nil even though my migration creates the table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I recently decided to change the name of a model. So I dropped the DB calling `rails db:drop`.

Using sublime text editor I did a find & replace for the model name, and I renamed all relevant directories to be in line with convention; including the migration file etc.

I deleted the schema file.

I called `rails db:create` to create the DB: no errors

I called `rails db:migrate` to create the tables and schema: no errors.

When I try to call a method on the model class... ('Set')

```
> Set.all
NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for Set:Class
from (pry):4:in `<main>'
```

For a test, I ran `rails generate model Set` and got the following:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 2042
      invoke  active_record
The name 'Set' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

So here it seems the model does exist.  But it doesn't exist in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is my model nil

It's not. It's unclear where you drew this conclusion from.

> NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for Set:Class

Name of your model (`Set`) is the same as [class from the standard lib](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html). Due to how rails' autoloading works, name Set is resolved to the stdlib class, not your model. Rename your model with a non-existing name (just as the warning suggests).